# Дописать результат выполнения функции, которая возвращает массив, в переменную

Tags: php

Есть ф-ция, в которую передается массив. Но он очень большой, и его надо разбить на несколько, разбиваю `array_chunk`. Затем `foreach` прогоняю по кусочкам этот массив. проблема в том, что в конце остается результат выполнения только последнего куска. Как сохранить все результаты?

```
$groups = array_chunk($arResult["ELEMENTS"], 50);
foreach($groups as $group) {
    $arOffers = CIBlockPriceTools::GetOffersArray(
        $offersFilter,
        $group,
    ....
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$arOffers = array();
foreach($groups as $group) {
    $arOffers = array_merge($arOffers, CIBlockPriceTools::GetOffersArray(...));
}
```